# NoSuchElementError Unable to locate element

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to execute the following test, but I don't understand why i have some weird errors and the process cannot be finished successfully.

Thank you!

const {Builder, By, Key} = require('selenium-webdriver');
async function example(){

```
let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser("chrome").build();

await driver.get("https://test.com/");

await driver.findElement(By.id('username')).sendKeys("admin", Key.RETURN);
await driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("toto", Key.RETURN);

await driver.quit();
```

}
example()

NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"*[id="username"]"}
(Session info: chrome=117.0.5938.89)
at Object.throwDecodedError (C:\selenium\selenuimDemo\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:524:15)
remoteStacktrace: '\tGetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6D68278A2+54818]\n' +
'\t(No symbol) [0x00007FF6D6796AD2]\n' +

I am trying to login in to a website, but it is blocked in the username and password fields